# Calling event handlers in dom elements

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'll start the question giving an example. In React, we can pass a event handler to the element without calling it directly and it will receives the event as a argument.

But using pure JS and HTML, we can't do that. 
I tried to execute the following code:

```
 <i 
   class="material-icons remove-button" 
   onclick="PhotoUpload.removeOldPhoto"
  >
    clear
  </i>
```

Instead of:

```
<i 
  class="material-icons remove-button" 
  onclick="PhotoUpload.removeOldPhoto(event)"
>
  clear
</i>
```

And just the second one is called. Why is reason for that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because inline, DOM level-zero events like this, when specified in HTML, are *evaluated*.

So you have to imagine that what's specified in the attribute is evaluated as JS, and:

```
PhotoUpload.removeOldPhoto
```

...when specified as JavaScript, is a *reference* to a function, not an *invocation* of one.

```
PhotoUpload.removeOldPhoto()
```

...is an invocation.

Contrast this with the *property* equivalent to the `onclick` attribute, where the situation is reversed - you would specify a function *reference*, not *invocation*.

```
someElement.onclick = myfunc; //not myfunc();
```